# Merge same object property name and combine other properties in one array object

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert from this:

```js
    const dataState = [
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3, time: '13:7:2' },
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 2, time: '13:7:2' },
      { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 23, time: '13:7:7' },
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3343, time: '13:7:16' },
      { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 443, time: '13:7:20' },
    ]
```

to

```js
  const dataState = [
    { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: [3, 2, 3343], time: ['13:7:2', '13:7:2', '13:7:16'] },
    { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: [23, 443], time: ['13:7:7', '13:7:20'] },
  ]
```

So far i have done:

```js
const dataState = [
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3, time: '13:7:2' },
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 2, time: '13:7:2' },
      { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 23, time: '13:7:7' },
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3343, time: '13:7:16' },
      { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 443, time: '13:7:20' },
    ]

    let uniqueName = [...new Set(dataState.map((a) => a.name))]
    console.log('uniqueName', uniqueName)

    let name = []
    let quantity = []
    let time = []
    for (let i = 0; i < dataState.length; i += 1) {
      if ('First' === dataState[i].name) {
        name = name.concat(dataState[i].name)
        name = [...new Set(name)]
        quantity = quantity.concat(dataState[i].quantity)
        time = time.concat(dataState[i].time)
      }
    }
    console.log([{ name, quantity, time }])
```

Issue with my approach are:

1. Currently i have to manually set `First` or `Third`, `etc...`
2. Only loops for the value i have set example: `First`, so need more logic to create another object for `Third` and `etc...`

Please ignore that I'm using `name` property as key identifier i know i should be using `key` for this.

Comment: k, and related to that, it's slightly smelly that you are using the names to identify which records should be merged together, rather than the key.  Isn't the whole point of the key to be a non-changing value for a record, when all other things could change? :)

Comment: I should i agree, i was just being lazy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop approach with an object as hash table.

```js
const
    dataState = [{ key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3, time: '13:7:2' }, { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 2, time: '13:7:2' }, { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 23, time: '13:7:7' }, { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3343, time: '13:7:16' }, { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 443, time: '13:7:20' }],
    result = Object.values(dataState.reduce((r, { key, name, quantity, time }) => {
        if (!r[key]) r[key] = { key, name, quantity: [], time: [] };
        r[key].quantity.push(quantity);
        r[key].time.push(time);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: perfect worked like a charm. back to the books on learning JS for me

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```js
 const dataState = [
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3, time: '13:7:2' },
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 2, time: '13:7:2' },
      { key: 1, name: 'Third', quantity: 23, time: '13:7:7' },
      { key: 1, name: 'First', quantity: 3343, time: '13:7:16' },
      { key: 3, name: 'Third', quantity: 443, time: '13:7:20' },
    ]

    
    var objKey = {};
    
    for (let i of dataState){
     if(objKey[i.key]){
       objKey[i.key].quantity.push(i.quantity);
       objKey[i.key].time.push(i.time);
     }else{
       objKey[i.key] = i;
       objKey[i.key].quantity = [objKey[i.key].quantity]
       objKey[i.key].time = [objKey[i.key].time]
     }
    }
 console.log(Object.values(objKey))
```